# Django Channels throwing me a strange error

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I am having troubles with sockets' framework for Django(Channels). I am using the latest version, 3.0.2. I've been using it in my several projects, but now I am getting a very strange, improperly described error. Here you can see my global routing config:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(routing.urlpatterns),
    ),
})
```

And local app routing config:

```
urlpatterns = [path("signup/", consumers.SignUpWebsocketConsumer.as_asgi())]
```

Consumer is a totally default consumer realization:

```
class SignUpWebsocketConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass
```

My app loads completely fine:

```
HTTP/2 support enabled
HTTP/2 support enabled
Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
```

The problem occurs when my client try to reach socket.
I am getting this error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I have been trying overcoming this problem for about 2 days, and still don't know, what cause this problem. Hope, that somebody here know something about that :)

Answer (score 1):

Hehe, this is not a bug of new version, but my mistake simply. If anyone has the same problem, checkout your settings.py file for a good redis server url. So my redis url config was incorrect.

Comment: Same issue, worked for me.